# regex for string starts with characters in range

Tags: regex, oracle

I have an oracle database and filter by regex to find entries with names starting wir a wetter within a specific range. For example, to find all names starting with A, B or C I just use:

```
.. WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (last_name, '^[A-C]');
```

but I am searching for a solution to filter for something like. Find alls names starting with "Ab"-"Ch". Does someone has an idea how to do this?

thank you. Phill

EDIT:
I forgot to say that I am from Germany and I also need to support special characters. Oracle regex has a special ability to use all variations of a letter. For example [=A=] means all variations of A like a, ä, Ä and so on.

The solution of chocochaos gave me a nice hint to solve my problem. For Example, if I want to find all names Starting with "Ne" until all Names Starting with "Ot" (including special characters) I can use

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (last_name, '^(([=A=][[=N=]-[=Z=]])|([=B=][[=A=]-[=E=]]))');
```

EDIT2:
another nice solution I found out is normalizing all name-strings to values wich contain no special characters anymore. For me the result is the same, but its definitely faster:

```
LOWER(convert(last_name, 'US7ASCII' )) >= LOWER('An') AND SUBSTR(LOWER(convert(last_name, 'US7ASCII' )),1,LENGTH('Be')) <= LOWER('Be')
```

Comment: Does `Bzzz` need to be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with oracle, but you could give this regex a try:

```
^((A[b-z])|(B[a-z])|(C[a-h]))
```

It simply checks for a string starting with

- A followed by b-z OR
- B followed by a-z OR
- C followed by a-h

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting specific case characters, hyphenation, apostrophies (i.e. `O'Brien`), extended character sets?

You could use:

```
WHERE SUBSTR( last_name, 1, 2 ) BETWEEN 'Ab' AND 'Ch'
```

Or, independent of accents:

```
WHERE SUBSTR( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2((NLSSORT( last_name, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))), 1, 2 ) BETWEEN 'ab' AND 'ch'
```

Or, if you are just expecting an upper-case followed by lower case character you could also use this regular expression (but it is likely to be less efficient than using `SUBSTR`):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( last_name, '^(A[b-z]|B|C[a-h])' )
```

Answer (score 0):

solution without regexp

```
where last_name >= 'Ab' AND where last_name <= 'Ch'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I well understand, but have a try with:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (last_name, '^[A-C][b-h]');
```

or

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (last_name, '^(A[b-z]|B[a-z]|C[a-h])');
```

if `Bzzz` needs to be matched.

Comment: probably not a solution, because 'Bzzzzz' should be accepted as well